# Simplest way to show infographics with big number and several text words on the side

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page with multiple items, each of them have a big number and some text  on the side (like "Big bank boom" on the bottom of [this](http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/small-business-credit-nfib-infographic-large.gif))

I found two solution.

- Use two columns with CSS layout for each item

The problem with this solution, that HTML will have big number of divs (one for each wrapper and two columns.

- Create a image with this big number and make it background for some div with the side text.

HTML will be much simpler, but in the case, if I have to change numbers, I will need to create new images all the time.

Can anybody recommend better (minimalistic from source code perspective) solution ?

Comment: Each Character is made of 8 bits, and images like that would be made of 1 Kbytes? 10Kbytes? maybe More? so of course, loading Characters is much better and faster, either in a div, or inside a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using images for such cases is a bad solution not only from a developer's perspective, but also because it gives a false semantic meaning to your document. A number should be marked up as a number - or as close as you can get - not as an image.

Now, what you can do, is create a div tag for example - or anything else that is semantically more close to what it is going to contain - and have two elements inside, the number as a span, or really, whatever at this point, you get the idea, and the text as a paragraph.

```
<div>
   <span>45%</span>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet.</p>
</div>
```

To make it look like the one you have showed us on that infographic is simple, I'll show you the code and explain it afterwards:

```
div {
   width: 500px;
}

span {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
}
```

This is the basic idea. You float your span element to the left with the number inside so that the number and the paragraph are next to each other. Increase the font-size of the span as much as you feel is needed, play around with the color or font-family to make it look better.

If more of these div elements are going to appear under each other, you have to make sure they are properly cleared:

```
div:after {
   clear: both;
   content: '';
   height: 0;
}
```

This also makes sure that your floated elements don't come out of your div, making it look weird in case a border is applied.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the new data attributes from HTML5 and pseudo elements with `content`. The markup is very minimal, and it's very easy to change.

**HTML:**

```
<p data-text="50%">According to some statistician, 50% of all humans...</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    width: 20em;
    padding-left: 7em;
    position: relative;
}
p::before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: .25em;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZZWK/)